# App not listed under device Settings --> Notification for iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, push-notification

I am registering for Apple Push Notifications and observing that my app is not listed under device Settings --> Notification for iOS 7. I can see this for iOS 6 though. Also, I have been receiving Push Notifications for iOS 7 so I am getting the token from APNS correctly. Any clue of what could be wrong for iOS 7.

Comment: if sam'solution's solution does not work and everything seems correct,  delete app & reboot your iOS 7 device and install app after few minutes. Worked for me few times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very small but horrible issue. Just go in settings and check all of your provisioning profiles related to your apps. You will see there are multiple provisioning profiles for your app. Just delete all of them and again install your app. Now it will work and your push will appear.