# How to add my jailbroken iPhone app to notification settings

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I'm working on an iPhone app with remote notifications, and it's set up already. But there is a problem: when I install it to the user applications path, everything is all right (I can receive a remote notification). But when I package the app into a `.deb` and install it to the system applications path, I can't find the item in **Settings > Notification**s and can't receive anything when the app is killed or enters background, either.

However, I can receive a notification when it's running in the foreground through the method

`application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo`

So, I have no idea what to do now. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Its all about **Provision profile** of your App. Just make sure all your provision file name (**Code sign, PEM file and Provision profile under setting in devic**e). If there is t**oo many provision profile** in setting, just delete keep it single and try. Hope you understood. Ask if you have doubt.

Ref: [App not listed under device Settings --> Notification for iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320673/app-not-listed-under-device-settings-notification-for-ios-7)